# Convert Textvalue String(Seconds) Value into Double (Second) using TimeSpan

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am going to Convert a string value into double...
Actually I want to convert Seconds into Mintues using `TimeSpan`
Value that i want to convert is `780.0000000656558` having 780 Seconds and remaining are millisecond's... i want to display `13.00000000010942633333` or for example 13mintues in case if there is no accurate perception

Am trying to using following Code

```
if (DownTime != null)
{
    DownTime.Text = sensor.DownTime;
    if (DownTime.Text.Length > 0)
    {
         //TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DownTime.Text).ToString()
         double DownTimeSeconds = Convert.ToDecimal(DownTime.Text).ToString();
         double DownTimeMints = DownTimeSeconds / 60;
         sensor.DownTime = Convert.ToString(DownTimeMints);
         DownTime.Text = sensor.DownTime;
         DownTime.ToolTip = DownTime.Text;
         if (DownTime.Text.Length >= 25)
         {
             DownTime.Text = DownTime.Text.Substring(0, 20) + "...";
         }
    }
}
```

i want to show output in Minutes... What Should i do
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't believe the .NET built in date/time data types have enough resolution for that kind of precision in milliseconds.

Comment: You're mixing up a *lot* of types here. For example: `int DownTimeSeconds = Convert.ToDecimal(DownTime.Text).ToString();` It's really not clear what your original value is meant to represent... surely the fact that you've got ".000" means that it's 0 milliseconds...

Comment: @JonSkeet : i want to display value it into mintes.seconds.. and above LOC that you mention is error from my side.apologize for that... and you correct it bcz am newbie in development.. thanks

Comment: Not directly exposed by your code, but one related pitfall is that `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` is broken-by-design, and rounds to full milliseconds instead of using the full precision of `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @AzeemRaavi: You still haven't answered the question about what your sample value is meant to represent. You said "remaining are milliseconds" - but how many?

Comment: @JonSkeet my sample value 780.0000000656558 showing 780 Seconds and 0000000656558 miliSeconds

Comment: @AzeemRaavi It seems like you don't know what a millisecond is. It's `1/1000` of a second, and not the full fractional part.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: thanks dude.. ok then what should be here for milliseconds

Comment: @AzeemRaavi: We don't know, because we don't know where your requirements are coming from. It does seem bizarre to have 780 seconds and then 656558 milliseconds, which is 656.558 seconds in itself... It sounds like you need to *very carefully* review the requirements. It's also generally a bad idea to store two integers as "x.y" - because 5.10 is usually the same value as 5.1 (as an example) whereas that's absolutely *not* the case if this is really (5, 10) vs (5, 1).

Comment: @JonSkeet: actually i am using third party tool and taking values from that(PRTG monitoring).. and going to convert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is giving me 13 minutes: try at your end please.:

```
        double time = 780.0000000656558;
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time);
        Console.WriteLine(ts.Minutes);
        //Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalMinutes);  // this will give u mintes.fractionalpart
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

[`TimeSpan.FromSeconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx) takes a `double` and includes the fractional parts (adding 0.1 here to make the fraction clear):

Using PowerShell (which automatically does the `string` to `double` conversion)

```
PS [64]> [TimeSpan]::FromSeconds("780.1000000656558")


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 13
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 100
Ticks             : 7801000000
TotalDays         : 0.00902893518518519
TotalHours        : 0.216694444444444
TotalMinutes      : 13.0016666666667
TotalSeconds      : 780.1
TotalMilliseconds : 780100
```

However as the commenter noted there is a limit to the resolution of `TimeSpan`: ticks, or 100ns intervals. Your fractional part is smaller than that. Thus in the example about the Ticks includes seven decimal places, but your first non-zero fraction digit is in position *eight*.

This can be seen by using `TimeSpan.FromTicks`, manually converting the string to a `long`, for the same time (minutes, seconds & milliseconds), but that first non-zero decimal digit is still lost:

```
PS [64]> [TimeSpan]::FromTicks(7801000000)


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 13
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 100
Ticks             : 7801000000
TotalDays         : 0.00902893518518519
TotalHours        : 0.216694444444444
TotalMinutes      : 13.0016666666667
TotalSeconds      : 780.1
TotalMilliseconds : 780100
```

Comment: While `TimeSpan` is limited by 100ns ticks, `FromSeconds` only supports full milliseconds. `FromSeconds(780.0004)==FromSeconds(780)`

Comment: @CodesInChaos true, but in this case that makes no difference because the fractions are at the 10ns range which is below the resolution of ticks.